# observer pattern - default observer

Tags: scala, observer-pattern

How I can make an observer as a default observer in the Observer pattern. For example in this example, from [here](https://github.com/paulocheque/scala-design-patterns/blob/master/Observer.scala):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

// Abstract implementation
trait Observable {
  val observers = ArrayBuffer[Observer]()

  def notifyObservers() {
    for(observer <- observers)
      observer.notification()
  }

  def addObserver(observer:Observer) {
    observers += observer
  }

  def removeObserver(observer:Observer) {
    observers -= observer
  }
}

trait Observer {
  def notification(): Unit
}

// Concrete Implementation
class SomeObservable extends Observable

class SomeObserver extends Observer {
  override def notification() {
    println("do something here: SomeObserver")
  }
}

class AnotherObserver extends Observer {
  override def notification() {
    println("do something here: AnotherObserver")
  }
}

// Client
object ObserverClient {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val observable = new SomeObservable()
    val observer1 = new SomeObserver()
    val observer2 = new AnotherObserver()
    observable.addObserver(observer1)
    observable.addObserver(observer2)
    observable.notifyObservers()
    observable.removeObserver(observer2)
    observable.notifyObservers()
  }
}
```

My concern was also, through making an observer default to see how I can notify statically instead of dynamically the observers.

Comment: say, you want to have a custom list of observers (like you do now), but also a fixed observer that is always there and does something specific?

Comment: @DanielL. , Yes, that's my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Scala here to try it out, but you could do something like this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Observable {
   val defaultObserver = { create your default here to do what you want }
}

trait Observable {
  val observers = ArrayBuffer(Observable.defaultObserver)

  ... (the rest stays the same)
```

Extra points for the ability to remove the default observer through your functions is you want to.

Comment: It's a great help. I am just trying....I am afraid that I am not understanding enough your last sentence!?

Comment: that it might come useful to remove the default observer sometimes. With this solution you can do `myObservable.removeObserver(Observable.default)` ;-)

Comment: OK, nice :D thnxxx a lot for this.